# How to get the latest row from the result?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT ann_arr.id,ann_arr.user_id,ann_arr.date,ann_arr.time,
ann_arr.venue_id
FROM ann_arr
WHERE user_id
IN (SELECT DISTINCT n2.mem_id AS frnd FROM network n1,network n2 WHERE n1.frd_id=n2.mem_id AND n1.mem_id='329' AND n2.frd_id='329') 
AND ann_arr.user_id !='329'
ORDER BY DATE DESC,TIME DESC
```

I am getting result as

```
id  user_id date    time    venue_id
995 399 2012-02-02  12:37:30    56
994 399 2012-02-02  12:36:06    56
993 399 2012-02-02  12:35:15    56
992 399 2012-02-02  12:32:40    56
991 399 2012-02-02  12:26:17    56
990 399 2012-02-02  12:23:06    56
989 399 2012-02-02  12:21:52    56
968 693 2012-01-25  13:27:11    1016
```

What i want the result must contain unique user id with the last `id` like for user `399` id will be `955`

*note
`SELECT DISTINCT n2.mem_id AS frnd FROM network n1,network n2 WHERE n1.frd_id=n2.mem_id AND n1.mem_id='329' AND n2.frd_id='329'` will contain users friend ids say `'399','693'` etc

//expected answer

```
id  user_id date    time    venue_id
995 399 2012-02-02  12:37:30    56
968 693 2012-01-25  13:27:11    1016
```

please help

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give a try at GROUP BY user_id, & changing order for date.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood corretly, you need to group by user_id:

```
SELECT ann_arr.id,ann_arr.user_id,ann_arr.date,ann_arr.time,
ann_arr.venue_id
FROM ann_arr
WHERE user_id
IN (SELECT DISTINCT n2.mem_id AS frnd FROM network n1,network n2 WHERE n1.frd_id=n2.mem_id AND n1.mem_id='329' AND n2.frd_id='329') 
AND ann_arr.user_id !='329'
GROUP BY ann_arr.user_id
ORDER BY DATE DESC,TIME DESC
```

Comment: can you edit your question with the expected results of your query?

Comment: I'm pretty sure my query should fit your needs. What does it return?

Answer (score 0):

Add id DESC to your ORDER BY clause.